# Toggling checkboxes using recursion | Recursion problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to implement a checkbox tree that has the following data structure for items

```
const checkboxes = [{
    field: 'ARTICLE',
    id: 41,
    name: 'Article',
    parentId: null,
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        field: 'article.colorCode',
        id: 42,
        name: 'Color',
        parentId: 41,
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            children: [],
            field: 'red',
            id: 43,
            name: 'red',
            parentId: 42,
            checked: false
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }]
```

Whenever I click on `Article` when it's unchecked, it should set `checked` property as true for `Article` and nested children and vice-versa(i.e. if a child is checked and it is the only child of its parent and that parent is also the only child of super parent further, all three would get checked)

Can someone please help me with a recursive function so that no matter what the depth of children is, all children get toggled? I just can't undrestand recursion.

Comment: To clarify, do all the children need to take on the value of the parent? Or do they need to toggle from false to true and vice versa? Can you please show how you are currently doing the toggling, are you using the `id` to identify what to toggle from `checkboxes`? Please show how you are doing this...

Comment: You have provided a data structure, but "clicking" is a user-interface thing. Can you provide the HTML how you map that to the data structure and vice versa, and what our click handler looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I would break this down into three pieces.  First, we need to be able to walk our nodes and alter the appropriate ones.  Second, we need a way to, starting with some node in the hierarchy, invert the `checked` property on that node and pass this new value down through all its descendents.  Third, we need to put this together with something that checks the nodes' `id`s to find where to start this process.

Here is a version which breaks it down this way:

```js
const alterNodes = (pred, trans) => (nodes) => nodes .map (
  node => pred (node) ? trans (node) : {...node, children: alterNodes (pred, trans) (node .children)}
)

const checkHierarchy = ({checked, children, ...rest}, value = !checked) => ({
  ... rest,
  checked: value,
  children: children .map (child => checkHierarchy (child, value))
})

const toggleHierarchy = (targetId, checkboxes) =>
  alterNodes (({id}) => id == targetId, checkHierarchy) (checkboxes)

const checkboxes = [{field: 'ARTICLE', id: 41, name: 'Article', parentId: null, checked: false, children: [{field: 'article.colorCode', id: 42, name: 'Color', parentId: 41, checked: false, children: [{children: [], field: 'red', id: 43, name: 'red', parentId: 42, checked: false}]}]}]

console .log (toggleHierarchy (41, checkboxes))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned react, I assume you prefer **immutable** way to do that, since that tree might be stored in state.

The function you want to use is: `toggleNodeInsideTree` function, and you should pass it id of the node you want to toggle, and tree data.

```js
 let data = [
    {
      field: 'ARTICLE',
      id: 41,
      name: 'Article',
      parentId: null,
      checked: false,
      children: [
        {
          field: 'red',
          id: 43,
          name: 'red',
          parentId: 41,
          checked: false,
        },
        {
          field: 'article.colorCode',
          id: 42,
          name: 'Color',
          parentId: 41,
          checked: false,
          children: [
            {
              children: [],
              field: 'test',
              id: 44,
              name: 'red',
              parentId: 42,
              checked: false,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      children: [],
      field: 'red',
      id: 45,
      name: 'red',
      parentId: 41,
      checked: false,
    },
  ];

  let setCheckedValueForNodeAndChildren = (item, value) => {
    if (item.children) {
      return {
        ...item,
        checked: value,
        children: item.children.map((x) =>
          setCheckedValueForNodeAndChildren(x, value)
        ),
      };
    } else {
      return { ...item, checked: value };
    }
  };

  let toggleNodeInsideTree = (id, tree) => {
    return tree.map((x) => {
      if (x.id === id) {
        return setCheckedValueForNodeAndChildren(x, !x.checked);
      }

      if (x.children) {
        return { ...x, children: toggleNodeInsideTree(id, x.children) };
      }

      return x;
    });
  };

  console.log(toggleNodeInsideTree(42, data));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @Giorgi. I was testing this out and I tested `console.log(toggleNodeInsideTree(44, data));`. In this case, attribute with Id 44 and it's parent i.e. attribute with id 42 should get checked as 42 doesn't have any other child other than 44. This basically means if a parent has just one child and that is checked, the parent should get checked as well. Could you please please help a little more. Really appreciate your efforts. :)

Comment: Also, another scenario that comes to my mind is if the nesting depth of a particular object is 3 ie. `parent > child > sub child` (assuming that 1 parent, 1 child and 1 subchild), if I toggle the `child` to true, then ideally `subchild` should toggle to true (already happening as per your code) but also the `parent` should toggle to true. Sorry for so many demands lol.

Comment: @JakeCano I don't see difference between your two above comments, it seems only thing you want is: if a node is *only* child and I check it, check its parent too? But what if `node->childA->childB->childC` and all parents of `childC` have just one child and I check `childC`, it means I should mark all of them too? In any case I would advise to open a separate question for that.

Comment: Yeah, both comments mean the same, just mentioned another scenario. And yes, you're right. A chain of nodes where each node has just one child, if I check any node, all its parents and super parents should get checked as well. Umm about posting another question, i think I'll have to specify the scenarios again. Anyone working with tree checkboxes can find everything in this answer, so will be really helpful. :) @Giorgi

Comment: Hmm, we have the `parentId` field in the data object in this question itself. Do you think that would be useful? @Giorgi

Comment: @JakeCano: Please ask a new question.  Feel free to link back to this one for context, and to post a comment here mentioning that one if you like.  But the new request is a significant change.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet. I have opened a new question for the bottom-up selection logic. Here's the link for the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777400/toggling-properties-using-recursion-checkbox-tree